# Are Questions about corporate accounting on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Part of personal finance is investing. Part of investing is picking stocks. To pick stocks, you need to understand accounting. As such, are questions like:
What does EPS (earnings per share) mean?
on topic. I think they should be.

Answer (score 5):

(Personal opinion, not an official mod view):

If they are genuinely written from the perspective of an investor, then probably they are on topic. But that doesn't mean it's ok to ask any question about the minutiae of corporate accounting in by just adding a stretched connection to an individual investment decision.

Comment: Yes, agreed. This.

Comment: I mostly agree with this, but we need to make sure that we don't require a question to contain some magic words such as "I am an investor" to keep the question open.  If the question is of interest to an investor, it should be on-topic, and it shouldn't matter if the asker is an investor, an accountant, a student, just curious, etc.